# WordPress - Contact Form 7 fields save to a different database

Tags: wordpress, contact-form

I know that there will be a database to be created at the initial configuration of CF7. I am wondering whether or not I can use a different database of my own (not the wordpress' database) in PHPMyAdmin, and is there an existing tutorial to do so?

Thank you.

Comment: You can easily create your own database with PHPMyAdmin, but why would you want to use a different database if you're using WordPress?

Comment: @ChavaG That's what the client wants, they want to save the data to their own database

Comment: I would suggest one of the two:  1) Let the plugin save data to the WP database, and add your own function on form submission to save it to the client's db as well.  2) Periodically sync tables of interest from the WP database with the clients database

Comment: I get the logic. So there's no way to save info directly to the client's db. Thank you.

Comment: Actually the first approach I mentioned is to save info directly to the client's db.  That is definitely possible.  At the same time, though, let the plugin save its data to WP's db to prevent messing up any of its integrations with WP.

Answer (score 0):

That could have some serious unintended consequences. You'd be better off putting a hook in your submission to ALSO add the data to some other database.

The reason is that plugins are quite integrated and there are many things that it tracks at once including things related to the user who submits the form. If you orphan some of those records, it might be difficult to reconstruct things, build reports, and do other sorts of maintenance later.